# Move all photos from phone to PC: easy method

Tags: sync, photos, file-transfer, mtp

The more I'm using an Android phone since years, the more I see a general problem arriving, for which I haven't found any **easy** solution after many attempts, involving MTP, SSH, FTP, adb, AirDroid, Shared folders, Sambadroid, etc. Note: I've read nearly all questions about this here on Android.SE.

**General question: How can a non-power user retrieve all his photos present on phone to his PC, in one or two easy steps?** i.e.:

```
Phone/DCIM/Retrica
Phone/WhatsApp/WhatsApp Images/
Phone/WhatsApp/WhatsApp Images/Sent
Phone/WhatsApp/WhatsApp Videos/
Phone/WhatsApp/WhatsApp Videos/Sent
ExtSdCard/DCIM/Retrica
...
```

For myself, I've done a Terminal Emulator script, that moves everything in a single folder, and then I'm syncing this folder to a PC folder with Resilio Sync.

But this is super complicated, my mother wouldn't be able to do it for example, and nor my brother (who is just an everyday-life phone user but non-power user).

---

Let's compare these two methods:

1. **Before Android 4: Connect phone to PC, use USB Mass Storage. Then it's like a good old standard USB flash drive. Search *.jpg, Cut, Paste. Done!** Important: a non-power-user can do it.
2. After Android 4: Connect phone to PC, use MTP (UMS no more enabled). Impossible to search *.jpg. Impossible to run a script. Impossible to run any standard backup software because MTP doesn't give a drive letter. Any solution that involves hacking to actually have a letter would be a power-user solution, which I don't want, according to question before.

*Remark: The fact that super easy method #1 is no more available might be done on purpose to force users to use cloud services, etc. but that's a whole debate that would be out of topic here*.

Comment: Have you tried [FreeFileSync](https://www.freefilesync.org/)? If you follow [my answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/110093/96277) from the sub-heading "Instructions" you would see that the software can be used easily by a non-power user and it also permits, if not searching, backing up only images.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method would be to connect the phone to the computer then enable PTP (pictures transfer protocol) on the phone instead of MTP.

On Windows, a dialog usually pops up just choose *Import images and videos*. Alternatively  you can  right-click on the phone icon in *Computer* and select *Import images and videos*.

The computer then retrieve ALL photos and videos inside the phone and copy them to a folder in the computer.

This [article](https://www.howtogeek.com/192732/android-usb-connections-explained-mtp-ptp-and-usb-mass-storage/amp/) provide further informations about android USB connections.

Comment: Thanks @esQmo_. I had removed long ago Autorun when a SD card is inserted. So I don't see *Import images and videos* anymore on Windows 7. What is the .exe name that does this? Then I can maybe manually run it.

Comment: If you have disabled autorun, then go to Computer , right-click on your phone icon select Import images and videos.

Answer (score 0):

enable developer mode and use otg cable and usb stick and copy pix to usb

Comment: What does "developer mode" have to do with OTG? And could you please give a few more details? A step-by-step guide would be appreciated, especially by "new users" not that familiar with the terms. Thanks in advance!