# Automatically transfer files from a specific folder to computer and delete them on the Phone

Tags: file-transfer

Given limited storage space I want to automatically transfer files in a specific folder on my phone to my computer and delete the original file on the phone to safe space.

What's the best setup to do this?

Comment: See if anything helps here: [how to sync phone memory with pc?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/49937)

Comment: @Firelord : The question you refer to is about syncing with means that the data would stay on the phone.

Comment: In that case, you can host a file server on PC and use file explorer apps like ES File Explorer to copy-paste content in it. Since it's not sync technically you can delete the files from phone after copying them.

Comment: @Firelord : I would like an automatic solution.

Comment: Perhaps [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.appfactory) can help.